# Installing Realm via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, realm

I am trying to install Realm (Objective C) via Cocoapods.

However I keep getting the following error:

```
Pods/Realm/Realm/module.modulemap:1:18: Redefinition of module 'Realm'
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

I've tried downloading their CocoapodsExample project but I get the same error.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods are you using `pod --version`?

Comment: having the same issue, using `0.38.1`

Comment: same issue on pod version 0.38.1  and Realm 0.93.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with CocoaPods 0.38.1, being tracked at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3886. In the meantime, you can `gem install cocoapods -v 0.38.0` and run `pod _0.38.0_ install` to use CocoaPods 0.38.0, which does not have this issue.

---

This should now be fixed in CocoaPods 0.38.2.

Comment: Yes this fixed it. Thank you.